# JUnit custom runner not working?

Tags: java, html, exception, junit

I´m trying to write a custom Runner which simply does the Tests in a random order. The runner:

```
public class TestClassRunnerForParameters extends BlockJUnit4ClassRunner {
    public TestClassRunnerForParameters(Class<?> type) throws Exception {
        super(type);
    }

    protected java.util.List<org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod> computeTestMethods() {
        java.util.List<org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod> methods = super
                .computeTestMethods();
        Collections.shuffle(methods);
        return methods;
    }
}
```

Now this works fine if it is not a parameterized Test. Is it possible to do this using a Parameter Test? Implementing the Parameterized interface?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the error is pretty self-descripting:

> Custom runner class TestClassRunnerForParameters should have a public constructor with signature TestClassRunnerForParameters(Class testClass)

Your class has no constructor with that signature. Its only constructor has parameters `Class<?> type`, `List<Object[]> parameterList` and `int i`. You should remove the latter two arguments. Plus, that constructor isn't `public`; you should add `public` in front of it.

Besides, if you're trying to build parametrised tests, you might be intested in the `org.junit.runners.Parameterized` runner, as it does exactly that. Here's a good [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/unittest/junit-4-tutorial-6-parameterized-test/).

Comment: java.lang.Exception: Test class should have exactly one public zero-argument constructor

Comment: That sounds like a problem in your test class, not in your runner class, doesn't it?

Comment: I have a TestSuite with a couple Testcases. Each Testcase contains a few Tests. I would like these Tests to be shown by name in the JUnit GUI in Eclipse. The number of Tests vary in the Testcases. I was hoping i could use a custom runner and the computeTestMethods() to solve this. Is this possible?

Comment: Not sure, but I think it's a different question, so I'd post a new one in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a constructor, (as advised):

```
public TestClassRunnerForParameters(Class testClass) {
   ...
}
```

And have it delegate to your constructor. Your constructors should be `public` in this case, as JUnit/Surefire is using reflection.

Comment: I did that same Error:  java.lang.Exception: Custom runner class TestClassRunnerForParameters should have a public constructor with signature TestClassRunnerForParameters(Class testClass)
 at org.junit.runners.model.InitializationError.<init